# How can I get the corresponding Update_ID for windows patch installation file?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, patch

I am writing a script in Power-shell that does basically the same thing that WSUS servers do,
Following the steps below:

1. WSUS server Downloads and installs the required patches on the client systems.
2. The PS script if patch is not successfully installed retries the installation on the client systems, by getting & executing the patch installation file (.cab,.msu,.exe) from the client systems.
3. The patches are selected by a independent process and send to a 3rd party location from where the PS script gets it.

The issue I am facing is the data in the 3rd party location for the patches contains UPDATE_ID as a patch identifier and I need a way to recognise whats is the UPDATE_ID for the existing patch installation file is.

NOTE: I can work through Hotfix_ID as the directory patches are stored in naming standards similar to "*$Hotfix_ID*". But single Hotfix_ID can have multiple patches.

The affected code is as follows:

```
param(
    $KbFailed
)
foreach($KbNumber IN $KbFailed){
    [array]$files_att=Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\*\*$KbNumber*"
    Write-Host "Installing $KbNumber ..."
    if ($null -eq $files_att){
        Write-Error "Required file not found for $KbNumber"
    }else{
        foreach($file_att IN $files_att){
            $file_extension=($file_att |Select-Object Extension).Extension
            if ($file_extension -eq ".cab"){
                dism.exe /online /add-package /PackagePath:$file_att  /NoRestart
            }
            elseif($file_extension -eq ".exe"){
                Start-Process "$file_att" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait
            }
            elseif($file_extension -eq ".msu"){
                Start-Process -FilePath "wusa.exe" -ArgumentList "$file_att /quiet /norestart" -Wait
            }
            else{
                Write-Error "File type $file_extension not supported"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned I am managing it right now with HotFix_ID(Kb_number), but would like to replace it with UPDATE_ID

Comment: _I am writing a script_, but you don't show us anything??

Comment: @Theo I thought that won't be necessary but nevertheless, I've attached the affected code. Thanks